# Has there been any deliberate implementation of combinational logic soft error correction in any consumer-level product, like a CPU/microcontroller?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, computer-architecture, hardware, computers

## Prologue

It is well known that many error detection, mitigation, and correction methods, such as parity or ECC, have been available in large memory banks, like for RAM, for decades now, and even in CPU caches and sometimes parts of state machines.

These are mostly large implementations of sequential logic where single event upsets from cosmic rays have a significant enough chance of causing a lasting bit flip, due to the smaller feature size, density, number of latches, etc.

Throughout most of computer history, the combinational logic of the CPU, or small sequential logic like singular latches or registers, have remained unprotected. This is mostly due to the unintentional electrical, logical, and temporal masking effects that are due to the low transistor count, number of logic gates, size of transistors, etc., which has made combinational logic soft errors due to SEUs mostly negligible.

Over the past few years, the reduced feature size has become a large concern because it may be making combinational logic errors common enough to be a real problem.

## Question

Thus, I was wondering if there have been any significant implementations of soft error mitigation or correction in combinational logic circuits or single latches/registers in any consumer-level product, like a CPU or microcontroller.

Comment: Yes. Have you done any research?

Comment: TI Hercules series. Infineon XMC1100. There’s many more.

Comment: @Kartman are you referring to the built-in flash ECC, or is there ECC in the "combinational logic circuits or single latches/registers", which is what I understood the OP to mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks *examples from an unlimited range of possibility* rather than posing a *specifically answerable technical question*.

Comment: @P2000, the Hercules series has ecc on the ram and other peripherals. XMC1100 has ecc on the ram and flash.

Comment: There's whole groups of folks working on fault-tolerant operating systems for space craft. I had a long conversation with one Ph.D. about his work in California, more than a decade ago. Pretty impressive stuff. Aside from that, there have been many approaches. (For example, the old Mot 88k allowed for two processors to be stacked up where each executed the same instruction stream but only one drove the bus. If the other one detected a difference, an interrupt was generated.) Just do some searching on appropriate research in this area. If you haven't found any, you've not really looked.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, ECC has been available in memory, busses and CPU in by simple parity checking or 8B10B coding and variants.

This is all aside from ECC used in communications links, of course.

An ECC scheme for soft errors is not to be confused with a ECC with soft error decoding. (Thanks to Elliot for the clarification in the comments)

To clarify a "soft error"  as meant by the OP is *"a type of error where a signal or datum is wrong. Errors may be caused by a defect, usually understood either to be a mistake in design or construction, or a broken component. A soft error is also a signal or datum which is wrong, but is not assumed to imply such a mistake or breakage. After observing a soft error, there is no implication that the system is any less reliable than before. One cause of soft errors is single event upsets from cosmic rays."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error

In contrast, "soft" ECC decoding involves reading signal a level with an ADC, and not a slicer or bit "detector", in order to assign a probability metric to a reading and improve ensuing maximum-likelihood decoding. This is cumbersome and expensive (and I'd argue mostly of academic interest) if applied within logic processing.

ECC in high-speed busses and high-density memory are not performed with such a "soft" metric, but sometimes the "hard" processing does involve a third "erase" or "invalid" level/flag to convey fault detection from one level of processing (sensing) to another (decoding).

Back to the question: as for ECC outside the realm of storage and transfer, there are logic and arithmetic techniques with built-in redundancy or detection, that deal with signalling errors developed within the logic processing, i.e. within logic cells, registers, CPU, arithmetic units etc. In fact, they are built precisely to deal with "soft errors", induced by cosmic effects, power supply effects, instantaneous interference ingress etc..

Have a look at **fault tolerant computing**, fault-tolerant logic, stochastic logic, hardware-redundant logic.

If all of the above was already clear, and you are asking whether fault tolerance against soft errors is built-in with commercial products, I think you are asking a very open and broad question. Perhaps some readers can point to evidence thereof, but for the most part I believe within the internals it's nothing more than simple parity checking.

Comment: "Soft errors" are transient errors that do not cause permanent damage, usually caused by cosmic rays or alpha particle emission. Soft errors in combinational logic are a much different beast than ECC or parity checking.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Aha, That's a good clarification. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

SET (single-event transients) in combinational logic are a very niche problem and the solutions are expensive. Any application that needs to worry about SET probably needs to worry about other kinds of radiation effects, so the typical solution is just to implement TMR at the module level rather than on-chip.

You suggest that SET in combinational logic are becoming an important source of errors in commercial electronics. I would like to see some evidence of that. Errors due to SEU in flip-flops are typically a much more probable event, and we don't see anyone getting excited about terrestrial SEU in commercial devices.

Comment: Xilinx KU series FPGA as well as Micro Semi's (Actel) RTG4 family of FPGA offer TMR as part of their product, either as a tool-level option or built into the underlying hardware fabric.  TMR at the module level is usualy a deal breaker from a cost and SWaP standpoint.

Comment: It depends on the environment and the failure analysis. If you are also worried about total dose effects or SEL then you might not trust TMR within a single chip. Yes, it is costly, but there are some applications where failure is truly unacceptable.

Comment: I think your point in favour of TMR at the module level (vs ASIC) is well taken. For evidence, the OP  is referred to commercial electronics used in naval electronics and/or avionics: chronometers, autopilot etc... these are redundant at the module level.

Comment: @Elliot - Your answer seemed to focus on SETs; not the entire gamut of radiation effects, hence the specificity of my answer.  My experience is in the space arena, with mission duration around 8 years.  Except for the Space Shuttle, I'm not aware of any applications that have TMR at the module or box level.  At that granularity, I usually see selective or block-level switchable redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Look up what amount of error correction goes into flash memory. Modern controllers (might) even incorporate aging status of a cell into the decoders. These kinds of memory (eMMC, SD card, NVMe, …) are really ubiquitous in all kind of consumer devices. From smart phones to washing machines.

High-speed in-device buses suffer the same problems as wide-range outside-device buses, so they use similar techniques. So, there's several computer buses that at least have checksums. But, surprise,  if you've got, for example, 8b/10b encoding on a bus (for example USB, or SATA, or things like PCIe, or a lot of other embedded serial buses), then you'll also use that knowledge to make the right 8b-symbol-decision – that's a soft-input decoder right there. This is 1990's technology.

Comment: Marcus, do you know of SATA implementations using a soft input? I've designed quite a few at Gbps rates and we process the 8B10B with hard-decision (bit-level look-up), only. Or perhaps we mean different things with "soft"?

Comment: @P2000 awesome :) No, I don't know any SATA implementation that would do that, indeed (which, by the way, I find surprising). I know that PCIe 6.0 will be both PAM-4 and have FEC; the FEC is a high-rate one, far as I can tell something like (256,250), and judging by intel patents and PCI-SIG marketing material, it can't be much more than even or odd parity bits; which, together with the presence of the CRC, would allow for a trivial soft-input ordered statistics list decoder. Admittedly, PCIe 6 isn't even released, and will be "server-grade" for years to decades... not "consumer electronics".

Comment: @P2000 I really meant "I find it surprising that I know no SATA implementation that even tries to do soft-decoding on 8b/10b", by the way. On PCIe links, equalizers are pretty standard, and I'd assume the same was the case for SATA (esp. that being carried over long cheapo cables), and I was always assuming that to at least require the ability to high-rate sample the analog signal (in fact, I'm pretty sure, I know a student who got channel taps from a PCIe switch). Now, assuming you have that info in SATA, too – why not use it? Sure, complexity, but honestly, even the 6b/5b decoder could just

Comment: be naively implemented as "In verilog, I have 32 modules running in parallel that spit out the distance of received (soft) codeword to their 'own' codeword, and I have a 3-stage minimum finder, after which I've got a maximum likelihood soft decision", far as I can tell, unless the latency kills this (after all, a 6-softbit distance calculation + summation could easily be 13 cycles of some internal clock, plus the maximum find, if we pipeline that, so, some 16 to 22 clock cycles would be my guesstimate).

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the amplitude in a jitter limited scenario is a poor predictor of bit-reliability, unlike in AWGN channels. But for PAM, yes there could be benefit from soft decoding, as is often done in TCM (as I am sure you know). But there's reason algebraic block codes are preferred (and they lean to hard decoding), and it's the attainable high speed (or low latency) and manageable gate count.

Comment: @P2000 ah... *jitter-limited* is the keyword that explains that to me (as someone coming from a wireless/fiber optical comms world). Yep, TCM came to my mind,  because quite frankly, letting one's synthesizer optimize away duplicate distance calculations and pipelining the result, and letting bad paths die early, kind of already nearly maybe quite resembles a viterbi kind of...